# Absolute and relative condition

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus, condition-number

Consider the mapping $x \mapsto f(x)$ with $f(x)=1+\|x\|_p$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^n \smallsetminus\{0\},$ as $x_i>0$ for $i=1, \ldots, n,$ and $1 \leq p<\infty.$

Compute $\kappa_{\text{abs},\|\cdot\|_\infty}(x ; f)$ and
$\kappa_{\text{rel},\|\cdot\|_\infty}(x ; f).$

Could someone please help me doing that? 
I don't know how to solve this problem.

$$
\kappa_{\mathrm{abs}}=\limsup _{\vec{x} \rightarrow x} \frac{\|f(\tilde{x})-f(x)\|}{\|\tilde{x}-x\|}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned} \kappa_{\mathrm{rel}} &=\limsup _{\tilde{x} \rightarrow \alpha} \frac{\|f(\tilde{x})-f(x)\|}{\|\tilde{x}-x\|} \\ \kappa_{\mathrm{rel}} &=\frac{\|D f(x)\|\|x\|}{\|f(x)\|} \end{aligned}
$$

Comment: $$\kappa_{\mathrm{rel}}=\frac{\|D f(x)\|\|x\|}{\|f(x)\|}=\frac{\left\|\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\| *\|x\|}{\|1+\| x\|\|}=\frac{\|x\|}{\|1+\| x\|\|}$$ my krel so far

Comment: It would help if you added the definitions you use.

Comment: $$
\begin{aligned} \kappa_{\mathrm{rel}} &=\limsup _{\tilde{x} \rightarrow \alpha} \frac{\|f(\tilde{x})-f(x)\|}{\|\tilde{x}-x\|} \\ \kappa_{\mathrm{rel}} &=\frac{\|D f(x)\|\|x\|}{\|f(x)\|} \end{aligned}
$$ I've used this one so far but i guess my calculation is wrong

Comment: $$
\frac{\left\|\frac{\left\|x_{j}\right\|}{\|x\|_{p}}^{p-1}\right\|_{\infty} *\|x\|_{\infty}}{\|1+\| x\left\|_{p}\right\|_{\infty}}
$$ that's what i have for now. Tried it the whole night to solve it